# eps export issue with Python and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, words, eps

I am having problems while exporting eps files from matplot lib. I want to edit in Corel Draw an eps file that was exported from matplotlib using, for example:

```
plt.savefig('test01.eps', format='eps', dpi=600)
```

After opening the file in corel, I get the following image

[image]

as it can be seen, there is a problem with letters. They are imported with wrong size and positioning; also they are converted to curves (although I have explicitly said to Corel to import the as text).

Importing the eps file with Microsoft Words gives the same results. It seems to be a matplotlib problem.

I have tried changing to Qt4Agg using

```
mpl.use('Qt4Agg') 
font = {'family' : 'Times New Roman','weight' : 'normal','size': 12}
mpl.rc('font', **font)
```

but it doesn't work...

Anyone having the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

Add these two lines:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.unicode'] = True
```